# Older movie about crew sent to research abandoned spacecraft

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is a long shot but I am looking for a movie I saw in the early 90's.  It involved a ship sent to research an abandoned ghost ship.  They go through "hyperspace" and find the ship.  The ship they find looks like pole with a ball on the end and it is spinning.  They dock with it and and find computer terminal and restart the computer.  I believe by pressing some crystals on the console.  They ask it some questions and get answers, form a bond but seem uneasy.

Eventually they crew of the rescue ship finds out the planet/star close by is about to implode and they do not have enough fuel to escape.  They end up using the abandoned ship as a booster to get away but not before the computer in the abandoned ship finds out and questions it. They proceed regardless, detaching after fuel is spent in the abandoned ship.  They escape, but the abandoned ship gets destroyed when the planet implodes.

This might be a TV movie, I am not sure.  I saw it when I was around ten so some details may not be 100% but I am pretty sure it is.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This sounds like the 1984 movie [*2010,*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086837/) the sequel to the classic [*2001.*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062622/?ref_=nm_knf_i1) Although there's no hyperspace everything else in the description matches. A Soviet crew is sent to Jupiter to find the *Discovery,* the ship that was abandoned after the events of *2001.* There are three Americans on the Soviet mission, sent along to help with recovering the *Discovery.* When they find the *Discovery* it's spinning end-over-end. They reactivate HAL, the *Discovery's* AI computer that had malfunctioned on the earlier mission. During the new mission they learn that Jupiter is about to be transformed, so they end up using the *Discovery* as a booster to get the Soviet ship get away in time.

Here's the *Discovery:*

[image]

Comment: The "hyperspace" might have come from interpreting the _2001_ movie, which if this was indeed on TV, could have played immediately before.

Comment: I'd guess the "hyperspace" bit is the aerobraking scene.

Comment: Thank you so much @joe L. I do believe this is it.  I am looking for a copy now to watch.  this has been bugging me for for about a year now.  My google searches have come up with nothing but Event Horizon which is a great movie but not it.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly there is also **Event Horizon**.  Its a sci fi horror flick which got okay ratings, but when I was young it was awesome! It has a similar premise that your requirements ask for.

Comment: Event Horizon was released in '97, which is hardly the "early nineties."

Comment: Good point. Just some late 90s movies might be confused with early 90s. But yah okay count it out.

Comment: True enough - it depends on how sure the OP is on the date. But 2010 does seem like a better match.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Yet the other answer lists a film from '84, and it's probably right.

Comment: It is easier to see a film from 1984 in the early nineties than to see in from 1997. OP said nothing about seeing it in its first run in theatres.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking this up yesterday and I think the movie is called " Sunshine " it seems really close to what you described

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Could you add more detail to this answer, e.g. a link or a description of the film, to make it clearer why you think it's the one the OP is looking for?